# AngularJS multiple nested ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have often done a nested ng-repeat to loop through child data when I have json such as

```
[
 { "accountnum": 1,
   "name": "foo",
   "subacct": [
      { "accountnum": 1-1,
        "name": "bar"
      } ...
    ]
  } ...
]
```

And then I use this pattern:

```
     <tr ng-repeat-start="a in cac.costAccounts">
          <td>{{a.first_name}} {{a.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{a.account_number}}</td>
          <td>{{a.description}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat-start="sa in a.subacct">
          <td>{{sa.first_name}} {{sa.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{sa.account_number}}</td>
          <td>{{sa.description}}</td>
        </tr>
```

This works.  But **THIS** time the data includes a third level; the `subacct` objects have a key of `subsubacct`.

```
[
 { "accountnum": 1,
   "name": "foo",
   "subacct": [
      { "accountnum": 1-1,
        "name": "bar",
        "subsubacct": [
        { "accountnum": 1-1-1,
          "name": "bar"
        } ...
      } ...
    ]
  } ...
]
```

So I tried adding a third level, but it does not show up (no console errors):

```
        <tr ng-repeat-start="a in cac.costAccounts">
          <td>{{a.first_name}} {{a.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{a.account_number}}</td>
          <td>{{a.description}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat-start="sa in a.subacct">
          <td>{{sa.first_name}} {{sa.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{sa.account_number}}</td>
          <td>{{sa.description}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="ssa in sa.subsubacct">
          <td>{{ssa.first_name}} {{ssa.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{ssa.account_number}}</td>
          <td>{{ssa.description}}</td>
        </tr>
```

So how do I get the third loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the tbody as this

```
<tbody ng-repeat="a in cac.costAccounts">
    <tr>
      <td>{{a.first_name}} {{a.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{a.account_number}}</td>
      <td>{{a.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="sa in a.subacct">
      <td>{{sa.first_name}} {{sa.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{sa.account_number}}</td>
      <td>{{sa.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end="ssa in sa.subsubacct">
      <td>{{ssa.first_name}} {{ssa.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{ssa.account_number}}</td>
      <td>{{ssa.description}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The reason I'm trying to do rows is so I can do expanding rows, so the user can view the detail row.  That's how I did it in my original single-level method.

Comment: @Steve One table can hold many tbody tags so you should be able to hide the inner rows in this cenario as well. Could you provide a plunker and we can sort this out there?

Comment: Let me give this a try.  It works for displaying the nested data, I'll try to wire up the hiding/showing and see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.. For tr tags will not work.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.cac = [{ "accountnum": 1,
   "name": "first repeat",
   "subacct": [{ "accountnum": 1-1,
        "name": "second repeat",
        "subacct": [{ "accountnum": 1-1-1,
          "name": "third repeat",
          "subacct": [{ "accountnum": 1-1-1,
          "name": "fourth repeat"}] }]
      }
    ]
  }];
  }]);
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<br>

   <div ng-repeat="a in cac">
    <span style="display: table-cell;padding: 3px;border: 1px solid;">{{ a.name }}</span>
    <div ng-include="'test.html'"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
 <div ng-repeat="a in a.subacct">
  <span style="display: table-cell;padding: 3px;border: 1px solid;">{{ a.name }}</span><div ng-include="'test.html'"></div>
 </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```